How to Open and Export the Latest Drawing Version of a Part in CATIA with SmarTeam API
I’m working with CATIA and SmarTeam and need help with a macro to open and export a part's latest drawing document as a PDF. Here is what I’m trying to accomplish:
Goal: I have a specific part, and I need to locate its associated technical drawing in SmarTeam, retrieve the latest version of that drawing, and export it as a PDF. I know that ExportData in CATIA allows me to convert an open DrawingDocument into a PDF. The challenge, however, is in reliably accessing the drawing document associated with the part.
Current Challenge: I can retrieve the part's ObjectID and ClassID through SmarTeam, but I am struggling with finding a way to navigate from the part to its associated drawing file. I’ve been searching for a function to retrieve the linked drawing directly but haven’t found a solution.
Approach so far: I’ve tried using methods such as GetDocument and GetAssociatedDocuments (which don't appear to work as expected), and I'm unsure if I’m missing a step or if there is a specific SmarTeam API function better suited for this purpose.
If anyone has guidance on the correct approach to retrieve and open a part’s drawing in SmarTeam through the CATIA macro, I’d really appreciate it!

Please define which programming language you use (as a tag). Please show some code which describes your problem

Do you use the SMARTEAM Integration Engine  libary from catia or one from smarteam?

In catia documentation, only smarteam integration checkin checkout etc. writes. It should be possible to write queries in the smarteam database. Must be able to open a piece.

If I have to ask in a simpler way, can't we perform search operations in the smarteam database?

According to the catia documentation you could use GetChildren to get all children of a catia document. For each child you could  analyze the LinkType. If you need more you have to check libraries of smarteam.

With GetChildren, I was able to open the data linked to the part with the Catia.Documents.Open method. However, what I want is to open the technical drawing linked to the product. I guess this is not possible. I have been looking for a way to do this for a week. The documentation is very weak and incomplete. Maybe this is what Catia does not allow.
